# Is it possible to pass data from an Angular HTML table to a component to then loop through its rows for processing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently I have a table displaying a list of values with one input box. The goal is that a user will fill in the input box in each row and then press submit. I then need to pass all the values like Activity Name, From Account Name, To Account Name and its corresponding Amount to a variable in my component.ts.

My thinking is that I could have an array object I could loop through for each row.

Example table:

```html
Activity Name From Account Name To Account Name       Amount
Deposit         Personal1         Bank1                 USERINPUT
Withdrawal     Bank1         Personal1             USERINPUT
Deposit    Personal2         Bank1                 USERINPUT
```

My end game is to have an array that I process using a for loop like:

```html
  for (i in this.AccountArray) {
    this.databaseService.getData(this.AccountArray[i]).subscribe(
    account_results => this.account_results = account_results
    );
  }
```

So in the example above I would process 3 loops, with loops 1 looking like this following: (Deposit, Personal1, Bank1, 50).

**Account.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="CmForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" name="CmForm"  >
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateselection">Enter Date you are processing.</label>
    <input type="date" id="dateselection" value="{{ yesterday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
    min="2015-01-01" max="{{ yesterday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" (change)="changedDate($event)"  class="datepicker" />
  <br>
<br>
<br><h3>Cash Movement</h3>
<table  class="responstable"  >
    <tr>

      <th>Activity Name</th>
      <th>From Account </th>
      <th>To Account </th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let activityresult of activityresults" >
      <td>{{activityresult.Activity_Description}}  </td>
      <td>{{activityresult.From_Account_Name}}  </td>
      <td>{{activityresult.To_Account_Name}}  </td>
      <td><input type="textbox" (change)="changedAmount($event)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<br>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit" /><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

**Account.component.ts**

```js
import { ActivityResult } from './../database.service';


export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  CmForm: FormGroup;
  activityresults: Array<ActivityResult>;

  constructor(
    private databaseService: DatabaseService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.CmForm = new FormGroup({
      'dateselection': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
  });
    // returns the starting set of Activities when page is loaded.
    this.databaseService.getActivity().subscribe(
      activityresults => this.activityresults = activityresults
      );
  }

}
```

**database.service.ts**

```js
export class ActivityResult {
  Activity_Description: string;
  From_Account_Name: string;
  To_Account_Name: string;
}


getActivity(): Observable<ActivityResult[]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/a';
  const data = ({
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <ActivityResult[]> res;
    })
  );
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<table>
    <caption>User actions</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Activity Name</th>
            <th>From Account</th>
            <th>To Account</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let line of data;">
      <td>{{ line.activity }}</td>
      <td>{{ line.from }}</td>
      <td>{{ line.to }}</td>
      <td><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="line.amount"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    { activity: 'Deposit', from: 'Personal1', to: 'Bank1', amount: 0 },
    { activity: 'Withdrawal', from: 'Bank1', to: 'Personal1', amount: 0 },
    { activity: 'Deposit', from: 'Personal2', to: 'Bank1', amount: 0 },
  ];

  submit() {
    for (let line of this.data) {
      console.log(line);
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace the console log at the end with this :

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.data.map(line => this.service.getData(line))).subscribe(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Which will trigger an HTTP call for every line in your data object. Try it, tell me how it goes for you.